# Can I view a new relationship without actually create one in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

I have a relationship like this

```
(student:Student)-[registered]-(class:Class)-[require]-(textbook:Textbook)
```

and I want to view

```
(student:Student)-[require]-(textbook:Textbook)
```

I tried to give a Cypher query like:

```
MATCH (student:Student)-[registered]-(class:Class)-[r:require]-(textbook:Textbook)
RETURN student,r,textbook
```

As I expected, only return a bunch of nodes but no relation in between IN THE GRAPH VIEW.

The table view is looks like:

```
student, r, textbook
-----------------------
{student 1} {} {book1}
{student 1} {} {book2}
{student 1} {} {book3}
{student 1} {} {book4}
{student 1} {} {book5}

{student 2} {} {book1}
{student 2} {} {book2}
{student 2} {} {book3}
{student 2} {} {book4}
{student 2} {} {book5}
```

So the question is: Is there a way I can view the relationship in the graph view without actually create one?

I already have a lot of relationship connected to Student, so I don't want to add that relationship in the database or it will looks messy.

Thank you for help.

---

updated:
The apoc.create.vRelationship works.

The only thing is if I try to return (student)-[require]-(book)-[require]-(student), this actually gives duplicate relationships. Is there a way to create the vRelationship only if the same label does exist already or show DISTINCT rel?

```
         --require--       --required--student2
student1 --require-- book1 --required--student3
         --require--       --required--student4
```

but I want

```
                           --required--student2
student1 --require-- book1 --required--student3
                           --required--student4
```

Answer (score 0):

The `r` relationships **are** actually being returned. When the table shows `{}` for `r`, it just means that there are no properties in `r`.

If you want to see something other than an empty map, you can change the `RETURN` clause to use `TYPE(r)` in place of `r`.

*By the way, you seem to have a number of syntax errors.
Relationship types must be preceded by a colon (":") when used in a Cypher pattern. If `registered` is supposed to be a type, then you must use `[:registered]` instead of `[registered]`.*

Answer (score 0):

As for viewing a graph including elements that don't actually exist in the graph, you need virtual relationships.

You can use [virtual relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/virtual/virtual-nodes-rels/) using [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/4.0/)

Here's an example of usage:

```
MATCH (student:Student)-[:registered]-(:Class)-[:require]-(textbook:Textbook)
RETURN student, textbook, apoc.create.vRelationship(student, 'require', {}, textbook) as rel
```

EDIT

To ensure you only get one relationship per student/textbook pairing and avoid duplicates, you'll need to ensure the rows are distinct for those nodes before you create the virtual relationship between them:

```
MATCH (student:Student)-[:registered]-(:Class)-[:require]-(textbook:Textbook)
WITH DISTINCT student, textbook
RETURN student, textbook, apoc.create.vRelationship(student, 'require', {}, textbook) as rel
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely do the trick. The only thing is if I try to return (student)-[require]-(book)-[require]-(student), this actually gives duplicate relationships. Is there a way to create the vRelationship only if the same label does exist already or show DISTINCT rel?

Comment: Just edited my answer, you need DISTINCT nodes before you create the vRelationship.